# How to apply delay for a single user in django without disturbing the whole server?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am building a django website and for certain reasons I have to send an email to user containing a link consisting of a token, although the token is always unique and is of 100 alphanumeric characters yet I want to delay the loading time of the user if link with wrong token is used.

The function related to this in my `views.py` is something like this-

```py
import time
def my_function(request,token):
    if User.objects.filter(uid=token):
        return HttpResponse("Yes")
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
        return HttpResponse("No")
```

But the problem here is that the sleep function not only affects the current user but instead the whole server.

Is there any possible way to add this delay in backend or in frontend?
If not then is there any other way to punish for entering url with wrong token?

Comment: You don't punish the response, you need to build in a system that will automatically deny the next request, Seeing as you don't appear to be using a user object, it'll probably have to be by session or something else which may have its own pitfalls

Comment: Although, since you mentioned front end, your solution above might suffice based on the response you receive (sleeping on front end)